# Selendroid: How to get image of RadioButton

Tags: android, selendroid

I'm using [selendroid](http://selendroid.io/) to test native android application. 
I need to read displayed image of `RadioButton` (it's an icon that can change).

I tried following approaches:

1) Using [WebElement](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html). WebElement interface doesn't have any method like `getImage`. I suppose that [`getAttribute()`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) should be used (I'm using it in web selenium), but I don't know which attributes are supported (`image`, `drawable`, `button`, `android:button` are not..)

2) Calling [driver.getPageSource()](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource--). This looked promising, but XML like this was returned:

```
<LinearLayout name="" label="" value="" ref="461c3985-6e34-df57-fd11-070646350c40" id="" shown="true">
    <rect x="206" y="279" height="64" width="78"/>
    <RadioButton name="" label="" value="" ref="520242c7-8a82-3779-ba07-c926c271c58f" id="" shown="true">
        <rect x="206" y="279" height="64" width="78"/>
    </RadioButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

So it doesn't contain any useful information

3) Finaly I used [DDMS - Android Debug Monitor](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) and dumped view hierarchy and even here I couldn't find the image.

**Questions:**

1. How can I read the image of `RadioButton` (and of `CheckBox` and `ImageView`) using [selendroid](http://selendroid.io/)?
2. Which attributes can be used in [`getAttribute()`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String))? Are they listed somewhere?

Comment: you should have at least one property to find it... :(

Comment: I don't follow. I don't have problem to localize `RadioButton` element, but to read an image of it.